# Switch column and rows of table

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have designed a grid using handson table. The table has roughly 15 columns (each column 100px) and only 5 rows. In total all columns will be 1500px wide, which cannot be shown on one screen, we need to use scroll bar, which is inconvenient.

I'd like to **"rotate"** the table, so that the table will have 6 columns `900px (150px*6)` and 15 rows `300px (20px*15)`. This will fit most screen sizes.

I have searched their doc, I have found a `getCellRenderer`, but there is no `setCellRenderer`. I'd like to know, if it is possible to do this programmatically.

Any hints are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider handsontable data as an 2D array. You can get `handsontable` data (or build your own 2D array), transpose it and then reload that returned data to `handsontable`.

I create a jsfiddle, so you can take a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/rdhanh/zo9517yo/2

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Yes, basically we need to rotate the 2d array and also assign cell renderer individually.